# @dataProvider or @depends can I use it?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a class (called `FormFilters`), that class calls its methods within one method, in this case `getProject`.

```
class FormFilters extends KernelTestCase 
{
    public function getProject($filters)
    {
        $this->filters = $filters;
        $this->getWhere($this->filters);
    }

    public function getWhere()
    {
        if ($this->filters->isValid()) {
            $this->sql = $this->filterName($this->filters->get('name')->getData());
        }
    }

    public function filterName() 
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

This is `getProject` method test:

```
public function test_getProject()
{
    $formInterface = $this->createMock('Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface');

    $formInterface
        ->expects($this->at(0))
        ->method('isValid')
        ->willReturn(true); // come into conditional

    $formInterface
        ->expects($this->at(1))
        ->method('get')
        ->with('name')
        ->will($this->returnSelf());

    $formInterface
        ->expects($this->at(2))
        ->method('getData')
        ->will('data example');  

    $formFilters = new FormFilters();
    $formFilters->getProject($formInterface); // my mock
}
```

So far all right. Now, I want to test `getWhere` method, I could do it independently, but if `getProject` has the same test (called to `getWhere` method), could I use the annotations `@dataProvider` or `@depends`, like this (example) :

```
/**
 * @depends or/and @dataProvider test_getProject
 */
 public function test_getWhere($dataToDepends)
 {
     // ... test ready !
 }
```

It's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current set-up, positive case for getWhere() is already tested (in scope of test_getProject()). So, **what is left to test** in getWhere() is a negative case, when interpreter does not go inside of IF.

Test could be:

```
public function test_getWhere_invalid_filters()
{
    $formInterface->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('isValid')
                    ->willReturn(false);
    $formInterface->expects($this->never())
                    ->method('get');
    $formInterface->expects($this->never())
                    ->method('getData');

    $formFilters = new FormFilters();
    //todo: inject $formInterface into $formFilterssomehow at this line.

    $formFilters->getWhere();
}
```

Regarding your question with **@depends** - it's usually used when second test can not be executed before first is done. For example, first case creates some entity in database, and second test tries to delete entity, created in previous test. Another example - a static property of class, set in one test and expected to be read in another test. Generally speaking, having dependent tests, as well as dependent code units is not encouraged. And anyway, it's not your case, not what you need for the test.

Regarding **@dataProvider** - it's pretty usefull annotation. It allows to separate logic of the test from tested data. And also it allows to re-use same test with different data sets. Test, posted above, with @dataProvider will look like:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider getWhere_invalid_filters_data_provider
*/
public function test_getWhere_invalid_filters($isValid, $getCallsCount, $getDataCallsCount)
{
    $formInterface->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('isValid')
                    ->willReturn($isValid);
    $formInterface->expects($this->exactly($getCallsCount))
                    ->method('get');
    $formInterface->expects($this->exactly($getDataCallsCount))
                    ->method('getData');

    $formFilters = new FormFilters();
    //todo: inject $formInterface into $formFilterssomehow at this line.

    $formFilters->getWhere();
}

public function getWhere_invalid_filters_data_provider()
{
    return [
        'case 1' => [
             'isValid' => false,
             'getCallsCount' => 0,
             'getDataCallsCount' => 0,
        ],
    ];
}
```